# Squared Euclidean distance with Row Major Matrix Eigen C++

Tags: c++, eigen, euclidean-distance

Due to the fact that i plan to pass numpy arrays into my C++ code with pybind11, naturally i would like to compute with Row Major matrices. I found a (one liner) implementation of the squared euclidean distance on stack

```
typedef Eigen::MatrixXd Matrix;
void squared_dist(const Matrix& X1, const Matrix& X2, Matrix& D) {
    D = ((-2 * X1.transpose() * X2).colwise() + X1.colwise().squaredNorm().transpose()).rowwise() + X2.colwise().squaredNorm();
}
```

But this requires X1, X2, and D to be the default Column Major Matrix. How would i implement a similar one-liner for Row Major Matrices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a templated version of that one-liner function so that it can accept RowMajor as well as ColMajor `Eigen::Matrix` arguments:

```
template<class T>
void squared_dist(const T& X1, const T& X2, T& D) {
    D = ((-2 * X1.transpose() * X2).colwise() + X1.colwise().squaredNorm().transpose()).rowwise() + X2.colwise().squaredNorm();
}
```

[This godbolt demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hs4bP7ocK) shows how that function can be used in a code.

Comment: My issue is more to do with the operations such as the use of `.colwise()` and `.rowwise()` to properly calculate for a `RowMajorMatrix`. The example above i believe assumes that the inputs X1 and X2 are Col Major. see the following https://godbolt.org/z/dP867ro4h , D should return a X1.rows() by X2.rows() matrix

Comment: No, there is no such assumption. The linked example in my answer shows that the templated function gives the same result for both matrices with RowMajor storage order (typedef `MatrixRM`) and matrices stored with ColMajor order (typedef `Matrix`). The only assumption that is made is that all the three matrices that are passed as arguments to the function have the same storage order. The result of the member functions `.colwise()` and `.rowwise()`  does not depend on the matrices' storage order.